# Line integral: $f(x,y)=g(\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functions, line-integrals

I have to calculate line integral of curve $C=[R\cos{t},R\sin{t}],\;t\in\left<0,2\pi\right>$, and $f(x,y)=g(\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2})$, where $R$ is real constant and $g$ is real function of one real variable.

I am confused, what should I do with $f(x,y)=g(\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2})$. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I=\int_Cf(x,y)dl=\int_Cg\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}\right)dl$$
On the given curve $C$, you have $x^2+y^2=R^2$, so $$I=\int_Cg(R^{2/3})dl=g(R^{2/3})\int_C dl=2\pi R g(R^{2/3})$$

Comment: Can you please explain it littlebit more for me? Why $g(R^3)$ and not $g(\sqrt[3]{R^2})$?

Comment: Should the answer be $2\pi R g(R^{\frac{2}{3}})$?

Comment: You are right. I've just typed too fast. I'll fix it.